# Get name of focused activity regardless of owner

Tags: android, android-activity

Is there a way in android to get the name of the activity (package.activityclass) of whatever activity has focus? I don't have root permissions, but I'm willing to write this with Device Admin or Accessability if it calls for it.

For example, if the camera is up, you would get "com.android.camera.CameraActivity" (or whatever the class is.)

If such a facility doesn't exist, that would make sense too, considering the security issues that come with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is use the [`ActivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) APIs, like [`getRunningTasks()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29)